# Could "edited x mins ago" tooltips possibly contain the summary instead of/in addition to the timestamp?

Tags: feature-request, tooltips, edit-summary

Under questions and answers, we get the little `edited x min ago`, `edited x hour ago`, etc. When mousing over this text, we get the raw timestamp.

I think that it would be more useful if the tooltip would also give the Summary that the editor entered when they submitted the edit. Perhaps instead of or in addition to the timestamp.

Comment: I would prefer not instead of; all relative timestamps on the site have tooltips with absolute versions, there's no reason to break that in this one case

Comment: Has there been any movement on this proposal?

Comment: This has also been suggested in [another, later question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145691/please-change-the-tooltip-shown-in-the-edit-details).

Answer (score 9):

This would make the edit revision field at least a bit useful.

I'm not gonna say that now it's useless, but it's very close at being so. The only way to see it is in the edit revision list, which also shows next to it the actual change, so it's only needed if the reason for the change can't be inferred from the diff... Which is extremely rare.