# Please change the tooltip shown in the edit details

Tags: feature-request, edits, tooltips

When hovering over the **edited [whenever] ago** link on a person's question, could we please show the edit comment in the tooltip rather than the exact time of the edit?

Showing the exact time of the edit is quite useless, especially when you've already told me how long ago it was edited. Showing me the edit comment could be useful if I'm looking at the post and going "Hmmm, what did the last edit change?", or "Damn that question is still ugly and needs some work!".

In summary: the tooltip contents should tell me *what*, not *when*.

Here are a couple of examples from question's I've [just](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12233711/file-mime-type-checking) [edited](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12233789/cant-get-admin-access-to-my-sites-facebook-comment-box):

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Showing the exact time is just a behavior common across the site. Hovering over the time *always* shows the exact timestamp. It wouldn't make much sense to all of a sudden show something else in one spot.

I'd be in favor of making the "edited" text in front of it have that tooltip, though.

Comment: Yep, that would be okay as well.